# Does the equation $x^3+y^3+2z^3=0$ have any non-trivial pairwise co-prime integer solutions?

Tags: diophantine-equations

I know for any pairwise co-prime integers $x,y,z$ that $$x^3+y^3+z^3\neq 0$$ $$x^3+y^3+3z^3\neq 0$$ Do we also have $$x^3+y^3+2z^3\neq 0?$$ Any Hints?

Comment: Ok! But you should change the title please!

Comment: Trivial answers as mentioned below: $(x, y, z) \in \{(a,-a,0), (a,a,-a)\}$. In these cases clearly $x,y,z$ are not coprime so these don't qualify.

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: ... have any pairwise co-prime integer solutions?

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1056636_diophantine_equation_3rd_degree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no non-trivial solutions.  A proof that there are no non-trivial solutions of the closely related equation:

$$x^3+y^3=2z^3$$

is given in Sierpinski's *Elementary Theory of Numbers*, Chapter 2 page 79, which may be accessed [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/mon/mon42/mon4202.pdf) (which I found via [here](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.dl-catalog-556369c7-b6cc-4a5b-be36-bfc8e0ca7cfa)). Then it just needs to be noted that a solution of either one of these equations would provide a solution of the other by change of sign of $z$.

Comment: There should be also a proof by Euler in *L. Euler, Algebra 2 (1770), Art. 247; French transl., 2 (1774) 355-360; Opera Omnia I (1) 491*

Comment: Then there is also *On the equation $x^3+y^3=2z^3$* by A. Wakulicz 1957, can be viewed online [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-the-equation-x%C2%B3%2By%C2%B3%3D2z%C2%B3-Wakulicz/d4b809e913f1be024e9a98d77b5a41452adf26d6)